# Rails won't run anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded to Yosemite on my MAC.  Rails was working fine.  Then I needed to re-install brew.  Now, Rails doesn't run.  Not sure if the brew install caused my problems or not.

I get this when running `$ rails s`:

```
 /Users/davidburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/  davidburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/  libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
```

If I look in /usr/local/opt - there is a file `openssl` but not a folder with that name. Is that the problem?

I just ran this:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Bundle Install gives me:

```
Davids-iMac-2:ndeavor2 davidburton$ bundle install
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/davidburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-   p484@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb":   dlopen(/Users/davidburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-  darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded:   /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

This line

```
image not found - /Users/davidburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle
```

I look using finder and it's there.

Comment: have you tried running bundle install or bundle update since the change?

Comment: Bundle install also gives me errors.  I'll post in question.

Comment: try `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary --with-gcc=clang`

Comment: Also this might help `brew install openssl`
`brew link openssl --force`

Comment: `$ brew install openssl brew link openssl --force
Error: No available formula for brew
Searching formulae...
brew-gem  brew-pip  nodebrew
Searching taps...
homebrew/php/brew-php-switcher`

Comment: `$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary --with-gcc=clang
Removing /Users/davidburton/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484
Removing /Users/davidburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484
Checking requirements for osx.
ERROR: '/usr/local/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`

Comment: Homebrew doctor gave me lots of errors!

Comment: Should I remove Homebrew?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You probably switched to the wrong ruby version. Try running `rvm implode` then `gem install rails`

Answer (score 0):

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/  libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
```

Try this http://www.dinduks.com/rails-cannot-load-such-file-openssl/

Comment: Rails was running fine before I re-installed homebrew. I'm wondering how openssl stopped working?

Comment: Have you fixed it? Or there are new errors? I don't know exactly, but maybe they change smth in Yosemite due to preveious OpenSSL heartbleed security problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Upgrading your RVM to the latest version, and also update your brew, you'd still find few gems not installing, if you use system v8 settings, that will install your gems.